# How to stop exposing multiple endpoint at client side

Tags: wcf, http, tcp, endpoint

I like to confess in advance that I am not good in WCF. I was going through a WCF multiple endpoint and saw a single service can have multiple endpoint.

1) What is the advantage of having multiple endpoint in WCF?

2) See the config data and definitely notice that `mex end point` only used for TCP not for other binding, why?

3) If service has multiple endpoint then when user add service ref from VS IDE then multiple endpoint related data expose & added in config file at client side. Can we design service in such a way as a result only one endpoint related address will be revealed at client side? Suppose I have one service with HTTP & TCP related endpoint and I want when external customer will add our service from their VS IDE then they will see our HTTP endpoint address not TCP. So guide me how could I do this? How to design service end config file for my requirement?

4) Can we design WCF service this way that I will have one service & one contract but I will have two service tags in config file for single service. Suppose one service endpoint will be HTTP and one will be TCP... In this case can we specify same service name & contract name? Anyone can give me a sample config entry for my situation because I like to visualize.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MulContractService">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MulContractBasicBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="MulContractTCPBinding" />
            </netTcpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="MulContractWsHttpBinding" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MulContractService" name="MyWCFLibrary.MultipleContract">
                <clear />
                <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractBasicBinding"
                    name="MulContractBasicEndPoint" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IMultipleContract"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                    <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="test1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractWsHttpBinding"
                    name="MulContractWsHttp" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IByeWorld"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                    <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="test1" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractWsHttpBinding"
                    name="MulContractWsHttp" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IHelloWorld"
                    listenUriMode="Explicit">
                    <identity>
                      <dns value="localhost" />
                        <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFLibrary/MultipleContract/"
                    binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MulContractTCPBinding"
                    name="MulContractTCPEndPoint" contract="MyWCFLibrary.IMultipleContract" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWCFLibrary/MultipleContract/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/how-implement-multiple-service-contract-single-wcf-service

Comment: Good questions, but too many. Delete this and ask them separately in a coherent way.